# Prove that this is a sufficient condition for function continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that this is a condition for continuity of $f(x)$:

For any sequence $x_n$ $\rightarrow$ $x$ and for any $w$, if $f(x_n) \geq w$ $\forall n$ then $f(x) \geq w$ and if $f(x_n) \leq w$ $\forall n$ then $f(x) \leq w$.

I was trying to prove by contradiction but didn't really know how to proceed. I thought that if there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $\forall n$ $|f(x_n) - f(x)| > \epsilon$, there exists no $N$ such that $\forall n > N, |x_n - x| > \epsilon$. I couldn't show this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the negation of continuity. If $f$ is discontinuous at $x$ then there is a specific $\epsilon>0$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains points $t$ for which $|f(t) - f(x) |\geq \epsilon$.

Thus we have an infinity of points $t$ near $x$ for which $f(t) \geq f(x) +\epsilon $ or $f(t) \leq f(x) - \epsilon$. If there are infinitely many points to satisfy first inequality then we have a sequence $t_n\to x$ with $t_n\neq x$ such that $f(t_n) \geq f(x) +\epsilon$. But by given hypothesis this means that $f(x) \geq f(x) +\epsilon $ an obvious contradiction. A similar contradiction is achieved if there are infinitely many points near $x$ to satisfy the inequality $f(t) \leq f(x) - \epsilon $.

It follows that $f$ must be continuous at $x$.